# Can you run Compute Benchmark (GPU) using Geekbench 5 on 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, cpu, gpu, benchmarks

I would like to benchmark test my CPU and GPU. I have installed GB5 and successfully run the CPU testing from the command line using `./geekbench5`. I was wondering if I could also run the GPU testing on the PC.

./geekbench5 --help

```
Geekbench 5.3.2 Tryout : https://www.geekbench.com/

Usage:

  ./geekbench5 [ options ]

Options:

  -h, --help                print this message
  --unlock EMAIL KEY        unlock Geekbench using EMAIL and KEY
  --load FILE               load and display Geekbench result from FILE
  --save FILE               save Geekbench result to FILE
  --cpu                     run the CPU benchmark
  --sysinfo                 display system information and exit
[0223/120307:WARNING:src/halogen/cuda/cuda_library.cpp(1686)] Insufficient CUDA driver version
[0223/120307:WARNING:src/halogen/cl/opencl_library.cpp(691)] Cannot find or load OpenCL library.
[0223/120307:WARNING:src/halogen/vulkan/vulkan_library.cpp(1346)] Failed to load vkGetInstanceProcAddr: 

  If no options are given, the default action is to run the CPU benchmark.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using a demo version of Geekbench5. GPU benchmarking is a Geekbench5 Pro feature. Using the Pro version:

1. Run `geekbench5 --compute-list` to get a list of available GPU tests.
2. Run the desired GPU test with `geekbench5 --compute <test>`

From the [Geekbench5Pro CLI Specification](http://support.primatelabs.com/kb/geekbench/geekbench-5-pro-command-line-tool):

> You can view the Compute API available on your system with the following command:
>
> ```
> geekbench5 --compute-list
> ```
>
> You can then select one Compute API to run a benchmark with. For example, we can run an OpenCL Compute benchmark on a system that supports OpenCL with the following command:
>
> ```
> geekbench5 --compute OpenCL
> ```
>
> If you have multiple GPUs which support the same Compute API, you can differentiate between them with the platform and device ID numbers that appear before the GPU's name after running geekbench5 --compute-list. For example, if the output of geekbench5 --compute-list contains two devices under OpenCL, including 0 1 AMD Radeon VII, you can run the OpenCL benchmark on the Radeon VII with the following command:
>
> ```
> geekbench5 --compute OpenCL --compute-platform-id 0 --compute-device-id 1
> ```

Comment: funny, who's gonna pay them to run their simple tests.

Answer (score 1):

atlas@atlas:/media/atlas/3c8475cc-e6fa-4f4d-9de4-5d59fb829ebc/GeekBench/Geekbench-5.4.5-Linux$ ./geekbench5 --compute CUDA
Geekbench 5.4.5 Tryout : https://www.geekbench.com/

Geekbench 5 requires an active Internet connection when in tryout mode and
automatically uploads benchmark results to the Geekbench Browser.

Buy a Geekbench 5 license from the Primate Labs Store to enable offline use
and unlock other features:

https://store.primatelabs.com/v5

Enter your Geekbench 5 license using the following command line:

./geekbench5 --unlock

Running Gathering system information
System Information
Operating System              Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Kernel                        Linux 6.0.6-76060006-generic x86_64
Model                         MSI MS-7816
Motherboard                   MSI B85-G43 (MS-7816)
BIOS                          American Megatrends Inc. V3.10

Processor Information
Name                          Intel Xeon E3-1240 v3
Topology                      1 Processor, 4 Cores, 8 Threads
Identifier                    GenuineIntel Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3
Base Frequency                3.80 GHz
L1 Instruction Cache          32.0 KB x 4
L1 Data Cache                 32.0 KB x 4
L2 Cache                      256 KB x 4
L3 Cache                      8.00 MB

Memory Information
Size                          13.6 GB

CUDA Information
Device Name                   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Device Driver Version         515.65.01
Compute Capability            6.1
Maximum Frequency             1.46 GHz
Multiprocessors               6
Threads per Multiprocessor    2048
Device Memory                 3.94 GB 3.50 GHz

CUDA
Running Sobel
Running Canny
Running Stereo Matching
Running Histogram Equalization
Running Gaussian Blur
Running Depth of Field
Running Face Detection
Running Horizon Detection
Running Feature Matching
Running Particle Physics
Running SFFT

Uploading results to the Geekbench Browser. This could take a minute or two
depending on the speed of your internet connection.

Upload succeeded. Visit the following link and view your results online:

https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/compute/5939302

Visit the following link and add this result to your profile:

https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/compute/5939302/claim?key=572877